# How do I add two count columns to a result set when one count is not restricted by the arguments in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to write an SQL query that would return a set of data with a couple of count rows tacked on.  In this case I want to return a list of FRUIT that are ROTTEN in the year 2018.  I'd then like to tack on a column that counts the number of ROTTEN FRUIT found in the year 2018.  Then another column that counts the total number of FRUIT rows, by type, for the year 2018.

So given the following table

```
FRUIT    DEFECT    YEAR    ...
------------------------------
APPLE    ROTTEN    2017
APPLE    ROTTEN    2018
APPLE    ROTTEN    2018
APPLE    BUGS      2018
APPLE    ROTTEN    2018
APPLE    BUGS      2018
APPLE    BITTEN    2018
APPLE    BITTEN    2017
ORANGE   BITTEN    2018
ORANGE   ROTTEN    2018
```

I'd like to get the following result,

```
FRUIT    DEFECT    YEAR    DEFECTCOUNT    FRUITCOUNT
----------------------------------------------------
APPLE    ROTTEN    2018    3              6           
ORANGE   ROTTEN    2018    1              2
```

but the problem is when I limit the where statement by searching for a specific DEFECT, I can't get the total for the FRUIT type for that year.

Here is my query so far

```
SELECT   DISTINCT FRUIT
        , Defect
        , YEAR([Date]) As [YR]
        , COUNT(Defect) AS [DEFECTCOUNT] -- This returns correctly
        --, COUNT(*) AS [FRUITCOUNT] -- does return the correct number
FROM [dbo].[A_DETAIL_REPOS] dat
WHERE YEAR(dat.[Date]) >= '2018'
AND YEAR(dat.[Date]) <= '2018'
AND dat.Defect = 'ROTTEN'
GROUP BY FRUIT, Year([Date]), Defect
ORDER BY YEAR([Date])
```

Thank you for the help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE conditional `COUNT()` to get the `rotten` count.

```
SELECT    FRUIT
        --, Defect you only want 'ROTTEN' so you dont need this one
        , YEAR([Date]) As [YR]
        , COUNT( CASE WHEN Defect = 'ROTTEN' THEN 1 END ) AS [DEFECTCOUNT]
        , COUNT(*) AS [FRUITCOUNT] 
FROM [dbo].[A_DETAIL_REPOS] dat
WHERE YEAR(dat.[Date]) = '2018'
GROUP BY YEAR([Date]), FRUIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You want conditional aggregation.  However, I want to encourage you to use date comparisons for the filtering:

```
SELECT FRUIT, YEAR([Date]) As [YR],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Defect = 'ROTTEN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as num_rotten,
       COUNT(*) as num_total
FROM [dbo].[A_DETAIL_REPOS] dat
WHERE r.[Date] >= '2018-01-01' AND
      r.[Date] < '2019-01-01'
AND dat.Defect = 'ROTTEN'
GROUP BY FRUIT, Year([Date])
ORDER BY YEAR([Date]);
```

Direct date comparisons make it easier for the optimizer to produce the best query plan.  In particular, it allows the use of an index, if appropriate.